# JavaScript: How to create reference to parent object from child object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, this, bind

I have an object `X` which has a child `Y`. Child `Y` is an array containing an object with a function `Z`. I need function `Z` to be able to refer to `X` using `this` or something similar, meaning that it does not need to know the name of the parent variable.

Here's an example

```
let X = {
  a: 23, 
  Y: [
   {
    Z: function(){
       return "a="+this.a
       }
   }
  ]
}

X.Y[0].Z() //It must return "a=23"

let X2 = jQuery.extend(true, {}, X, {a: 878});
X2.Y[0].Z() //It must return "a=878"
```

As you can see, by deep copying object `X` to `X2`, simply by changing the value of `a` this should reflect the result when running `Z()` from `X2`.

At the moment `this` is not referring to the parent object, I have tried using `bind()`, but it is not solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need function Z to be able to refer to X using "this" or something similar, meaning that it does not need to know the name of the parent variable.

To do that, you'll have to bind the `Y[0].Z` function after doing the deep copy with `jQuery.extend` that you're already doing. This means that `X` can't be used directly, you have to make an initial copy of it.

Like this:

```
function copy(x, props) {
    var rv = jQuery.extend(true, {}, x, props);
    rv.Y[0].Z = rv.Y[0].Z.bind(rv); // ***
    return rv;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
let X = {
  a: 23, 
  Y: [
   {
    Z: function(){
       return "a=",this.a
       }
   }
  ]
}

function copy(x, props) {
    var rv = jQuery.extend(true, {}, x, props);
    rv.Y[0].Z = rv.Y[0].Z.bind(rv);
    return rv;
}

let X1 = copy(X);
console.log(X1.Y[0].Z()); // "a=23"

let X2 = copy(X, {a: 878});
console.log(X2.Y[0].Z()); //"a=878"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, array elements have no reference to the array(s) containing them.

You need to have reference of parent element,i.e.,X
If there are multiple objects like X,then you need to create a loop to access them.
Then find `Z` inside X .

In you case, `this` will only refer to method `Z`.